# Azure Web App VSTS Pre-compile Views (Not updatable)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

In my VSTS Build process for the build task I have the following flags set to pre-compile the views:

/p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true /p:UseMerge=true

This works fine and I can see the views are pre-compiled and the site is definitely faster.

However, I can't seem to work out whether either of these sets the flag to allow or not the site to be updatable, obviously I don't want it to be updatable but no amount of Googling has found a suitable answer and I'm not sure if there is another way I can check?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want to use the `EnableUpdateable` MSBuild property:

```
/p:EnableUpdateable=false /p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true /p:UseMerge=true
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, I can't believe I wasn't able to find this googling for the msbuild options but obviously googling for enableupdateable gets me plenty of results *sigh*

Comment: lol I cheated by creating a .pubxml publish profile (which is just an MSBuild file) and reading out the properties :)

Comment: I was wondering if all the /p parameters were direct copies of those found in that file..good to know 